# Android Getting Image from ImageView of MainActivity to Second Activity when onclick is called

Tags: android, image, android-intent

- I have 2 activitiesMain.xml & imageActivity.
- On Main, I have selected an image from gallery and it appeared in ImageView of MainActivity. Works fine!
- i have set up an onClick on this image.
- [NOTE : image is current displayed at ImageView of Main Activity i can see in App ].
- I want to show the image in my ShowImageActivity
- I want to know how to send this image to another activity and i also want to know its Path .

  TO send Path i can use the following code

  ```
    public void imageclicked(View view) {
  // TODO : GET PATH OF IMAGE
   String path ; 
   startActivity( new Intent( MainActivity.this,imageActivity.class).putExtra("image",path));
  ```

  }

  But how to get Path from view ?

  - i also want to know how to directly send an image to another activity.. your help will be appreciated..!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a `startActivityForResult` method which you call and when user select an image, your `onActivityResult` method will call, then you have something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily send your URI to next activity by:

`startActivity( new Intent( MainActivity.this,imageActivity.class).putExtra("image",uri));`